# Given a String of numbers separated by one or more spaces, find the 2nd largest number

Tags: java, arrays

So here's what I got so far:

```
    public static int findSecondLargest(String nums){

    String[] num = nums.split(" ");
    int[] numbers = new int[num.length];
    int highest1 = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int highest2 = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    for (int i =0; i < num.length; i++) {       
        numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(num[i]);
    }

    for (int numbers : numbers) {
        if (numbers >= highest1) {
            highest2 = highest1;
            highest1 = numbers;
        }
        else if (numbers > highest2) {
            highest2 = numbers;
        }
    }
    return highest2;
}
```

I'm getting an error on the line `for (int numbers : numbers) {` because it's a duplicate, but I'm still not sure why my code shouldn't work, since I want to use the full range of the array in the `for` loop.

Any suggestions? Also, is there an easier way to do this without using an array?

Comment: because you can't declare a new integer in your for loop with the same name as your array, inside that scope it has no idea which numbers you are referring to inside you for loop

Comment: I'm an idiot. Changed it to `i : numbers`

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz just changed it as you posted it hahah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int numbers : numbers) {
```

This is the same variable in both places. Is the variable `numbers` an `int` or an `int[]`? You can't tell and neither can the compiler. Rename that variable.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend changing the first numbers to i or some other variable.  The compiler may think that you are trying to run an array through an array.